# A debian install using KDE that does not require systemd

Tags: debian, kde

At some point in the future I may use systemd, but for the moment I gain nothing by using it and am happy with LSB. So I am not going to waste the time  upgrading it. On some systems I use Mint Debian 1. I always use KDE for my DE/WM. In the latest upgrade, plasma was removed because of dependencies which come down to a dependency on  systemd or a libraryof systemd. Is there a place I can get kde packages which do not require me to install systemd.

If not that then a place where I can find a tarball of all the kde source, so I can compile and install it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out the [Devuan project](https://devuan.org/)? It is a Debian fork free of systemd dependencies.

Comment: The answer is I've heard of it.  But I've never considered it./ I like LDME because it supposedly  makes use of some borderline nonfree stuff which does not require you to pull your hair out to use. I don't use straight debian for that reason, and I don't think Devuan will work either.

Comment: @Mouse.The.Lucky.Dog: I'm sorry, I understood you were able to switch distribution to get a systemd-free KDE desktop

Comment: @Andrea, thinking about it, what I maybe able to do is download and install to a VM. Then use the VM to get all source repos for KDE.